# VIM as c++ IDE - autocomplete

Tags: vim, debian, c++, gvim, ide

I'm still learning C++, but I know already some stuff. I used to use Visual Studio, but after I switched to Debian, I was working with Code Blocks.

Recently I heard about using VIM as IDE and started using it. Problem that appeared is autocompletion is not working. I don't know why, but recently C-P/C-N stopped working - it does completion only if a particular word is already in the code or in the code of another tab; so every time I start I have to type every first include/cout/class etc. without autocompletion.

I've tried to use YouCompleteMe, but unfortunately: `YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim 7.3.584+`.

I'm using Debian Wheezy (stable with backports) and it doesn't have vim 7.4 in the repos. I tried to add the repo from Jessie and - using low pinn - tried to install vim 7.4, but it wanted to remove a lot of packages (like g++ and many others), so I gave up this idea.

I'm not very good on Debian, I'm using it for like ~1.5 year, but more like work-machine, not something I need to learn everything about it, so I need some help in:

1. Installing vim 7.4 on Debian without removing half of the system or,
2. Make **YouCompleteMe** work or,
3. Make autocompletion in vim work (especially for C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> install vim 7.4 on Debian without removing half of the system

Installing from source is a good choice. Compiling `vim` is not difficult at all. You can read more details and instructions [here](http://www.vim.org/download.php).

> make YouCompleteMe work

Installing YouCompleteMe need some things more difficult but it's good documentation at [YouCompleteMe github repo](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), try this and tell us if you have any trouble.

> make autocompletion in vim work (especially for C++)

Another options for C++ autocompletion is using [OmniCppComplete](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion), it's easier to use and install than YouCompleteMe.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have removed 7.3 and installed from source v7.4, works pretty good, YCM is not reporting any error, I hope it will work :)